# Reloading a comboBox after changing it's values

Tags: javafx, combobox

I am populating a comboBox with items taken from a sql database when initializing the thread.

If anyone's interested:

```
public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1)  {
    if(arr != null || arr.length > 0) {
        for(int i = 0; i<arr.length; i++) {
            cmBox.getItems().add(arr[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

I have a part of my code that adds a new value to the sql table, and I want to re-populate the comboBox when that happens.

if I do:

```
    cmBox.getItems().clear();
    arr = sqld.selectAll();

    if(arr != null || arr.length > 0) {
        for(int i = 0; i<arr.length; i++) {
            cmBox.getItems().add(arr[i]);
        }
    }
```

It works fine, but I can't see the new changes unless I close and re-open the window that displays the comboBox.

No errors or anything, just looking for creative ways of re-loading a comboBox and have it actually show the updated values without manually closing and re-opening the window.

Comment: If you are reloading all the data from the table into a list, why not just call `cmBox.setItems(arr)`?

Comment: While not ideal, the code you've shown so far should work. If not, there is likely another problem and you should add a [mcve] to your question that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: @Zephyr arr is an array, and cmBox.setItems needs an ObsorvableList

Comment: You can easily convert the array to an `ObservableList` using `FXCollections.observableArrayList(Arrays.asList(arr));`

Comment: @Zephyr It still doesn't reload it. The new item won't show unless I close and reopen the program.

Comment: Then something else is going on with your code that you aren't showing us. Again, please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: @Zephyr If I make a button and set that to perform a method that does   

    {cmBox.getItems().clear();
      arr = sqld.selectAll();
      cmBox.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(Arrays.asList(arr)));}

 then it works. Otherwise it wont (say when I try to update it from a different thread...

Comment: @Zephyr Thanks but I think i'll just add a refresh button instead. Updating GUI from a different thread is a lot more difficult than just doing a button.

Comment: Obviously you're welcome to do as you please, but in my experience, implementing a faulty workaround is a lot more trouble down the road than just learning how to do it right in the first place. 

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a refresh button just run `comboBox.setItems(...)` when you add "a new value to the sql table" this should update the combo box here is an example

```
public class Main extends Application {

    private int[] data;
    private int dataCount = 0;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        data = randomizeData(dataCount);

        ComboBox comboBox = new ComboBox();
        comboBox.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                Arrays.stream(data).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList())));

        Button updateDataButton = new Button("Update values in SQL Table");
        updateDataButton.setOnAction(event -> {
                //Update your SQL data
                updateData();

                //Refresh List
                comboBox.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                        Arrays.stream(data).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList())));
        });

        VBox vBox = new VBox();
        vBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        vBox.getChildren().addAll(comboBox, updateDataButton);

        Scene scene = new Scene(vBox);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private int[] randomizeData(int additional){
        int[] data = new int[5+additional];
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            data[i] = (int) (Math.random()*10);
        }
        return data;
    }

    private void updateData(){
        data = randomizeData(++dataCount);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args); }
}
```